# Why does XmlNodeReader read in the closing tag in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following in an xml file:

```
<MyTag>Inner Text</MyTag>
```

In my code i have the following to read the xml file:

```
XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(myXmlDoc);
while (nodeReader.Read());
{
    string temp = nodeReader.Name;
}
```

After successfully reading the `<MyTag>` in the xml it reads in a blank and then moves on to the next tag.  Why is that?

Edit:

I have also noticed that the first element reads in correctly, however, the second element's inner text doesn't come through.

Comment: Why don't you use Linq2Xml. i find it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your loop is an empty loop since you have ';' on the while line meaning you move the reader to the very end without reading anything. Remove the ';' and you should have better results. Here is an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument myXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDoc.LoadXml("<MyTag>Inner Text</MyTag>");

        XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(myXmlDoc);
        while (nodeReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Node Type : {0}, Node Name: {1}, Node Value {2}", 
                nodeReader.NodeType, 
                nodeReader.Name, 
                nodeReader.Value);
        }

    }
```

And the result;

```
Node Type : Element, Node Name: MyTag, Node Value
Node Type : Text, Node Name: , Node Value Inner Text
Node Type : EndElement, Node Name: MyTag, Node Value
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Note that for the text node the name is empty since only elements and attributes have names.